# Cryptography resources for programmers

Tags: reference-request

As a senior programmer entering blockchain projects, i'm looking for a comprehensive introduction to relevant cryptographic tools/primitives, preferably one that puts less emphasis on the math and more on the usage.

Are there recommended resources for the mathematically uninitiated?

Comment: I think it depends on what type of blockchain project you are referring to. For example, privacy orientated chains will have zero knowledge proofs, while projects like bitcoin will have simple public-key cryptography, etc. For bitcoin, I found this channel on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCHBWzcGSrtoLYcasLwGvsow/videos?disable_polymer=1

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't want to be trivial, but, aside from different implementations, interpretations, enhancements, splits, forks and *fake actors*, imho, I think that the foundations are all in the original **Satoshi Nakamoto**'s **Bitcoin paper** and **relative references**.

I think that is the best starting point to understand mechanisms under the hood.

[Bitcoin: A Peer-to-Peer Electronic Cash System](https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf)